# Homology group of non orientable manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I think that if $M$ is a non-orientable, connected, compact, n-manifold, then $H_n(M,\mathbb{Z}/k)=0$ if $k\neq 2$. My proof is the following:

$H_n(M,\mathbb{Z}/k)\neq 0$ then $H_n(M,\mathbb{Z}/k)$ should be $\mathbb{Z}/k$. So $M$ is $\mathbb{Z}/k$ orientable, then it is $\mathbb{Z}$ orientable (contradiction).

Is it correct?

Comment: You haven't justified a single one of the statements in your proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H_n(M,M-x;R)= H_n(M,M-x)\otimes R$.  For each $r\in R$ determines a covering space $M_r$ of $M$ consisting of points $\pm \mu_x\otimes r \in H_n(M,M-x;R)$ where $\mu_x\in H_n(M,M-x)$ is a generator. If $r=-r$ i.e order $2$, then $M_r$ is just a copy of $M$, otherwise it is isomorphic with the oriented $2-$sheeted cover $\bar{M}$.

So observe that a non-orientable manifold  $M$ is $R$-orientable iff $R$ contains a unit of order $2$, which is basically same as $2=0$ in $R$. So if $M$ is not orientable , then $M$ is not $R$ orientable for $\mathbb Z_m$ where $m\geq 3$. That implies $H_n(M,\mathbb Z_m)= 0 $. for $n\neq 2$.